# Conversion point process to class image and return to same point process again

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, spatstat

I'll like to translate between `spatstat` and `raster` worlds without any original information damage.

I try to convert the point process (`ppp` object) present in longleaf data set in `spatstat` package in `im` class and after I try to convert the `im` class object in the original longleaf data set as a point process without success.

In my example:

```
#<start> ---
library(spatstat)
library(raster)
library(maptools)

# Compute a gaussian kernel smoothed intensity with longleaf data set
bw <- bw.diggle(longleaf) #First, defined bandwidth sigma 
im_census<-density.ppp(longleaf, sigma=bw,diggle=TRUE)

# Now I'll try to convert im im_census object in original longleaf Point Pattern ppp again
im_census_p<-rasterToPoints(raster(as.SpatialGridDataFrame.im(im_census)))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(longleaf)
plot(im_census_p)
#<end> ---
```

But obviously it doesn't work?
Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `spatstat` conversion between classes is usually performed by a function with a name beginning with `"as"`. To convert a `ppp` to an `im`, you can use `as.im`. The generic `as.im` dispatches to the method `as.im.ppp` which calls `pixellate`. Example:

```
X <- cells # or any point pattern
Z <- as.im(X)
plot(Z)
plot(X, add=TRUE)
```

In the resulting image Z, the value at each pixel is the number of data points falling in the pixel. The exact coordinates of the data points are lost.

To convert `im` to `ppp` there is no `as.ppp.im` method because this operation generally doesn't make sense. But assuming the image `Z` was produced by pixellating a point pattern, you can do

```
P <- where.max(Z > 0, first=FALSE)
```

Then `P` is a point pattern. The operation `Z > 0` returns a binary-valued pixel image with entry `TRUE` for pixels containing at least one data point. The function `where.max` finds the pixel centres where the image achieves its maximum, and in this case, that means all the `TRUE` pixels. To see the discretisation effect:

```
plot(X)
plot(P, add=TRUE, pch=3)
```

`P` is similar to `X` except that the exact locations of the data points have been replaced by the locations of the nearest pixel centres. Multiple data points falling in a single pixel are replaced by a single point at the centre of the pixel.

For more complicated manipulations you can use `as.data.frame` to convert an `im` object to a data frame, with one row for each pixel, with columns `x`, `y`, `value`. Then manipulate this data frame and finally use `as.ppp` to make a point pattern out of the resulting data frame.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, it is ill-posed. A `ppp` is a vector format which represents the coordinates of the points to double precision accuracy. On the other hand raster formats such as `im` and objects from the `raster` package contain a grid of points with some given resolution. So unless your points are perfectly aligned in a grid your task of converting from `ppp` to a raster format "without any original information damage" is impossible.

If you want a raster approximation of a `ppp` you can use `pixellate` in `spatstat` which makes a grid and counts how many points fall in each grid cell (typically 0 or 1).